# Query performance increase from deleting rows in SQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-performance

I have a database with a single table that keeps track of user state. When I'm done handling the row, its no longer necessary to keep it in the database and can be deleted.

Now lets say I wanted to keep track of the row instead of deleting it (for historical purposes, analytics, etc). Would it be better to:

1. Leave the data in the same table and mark the row as 'used' (with an extra column or something like that)
2. Delete the row from the table and insert it into a separate table that is created only for historical purposes

For choice #1, I wonder if leaving the unnecessary rows in the database will start to affect query performance. (All of my queries are on indexed columns, so maybe this doesn't matter?)

For choice #2, I wonder if the constant deleting of rows will end up causing problems such as fragmentation?

Comment: Ah, this is for mysql. Shouldn't have tagged both.

Comment: For choice #2 - rather than deleting rows after transferring them to another table - could you not reuse them. Flag the row as no longer in use & search for those when you need to track current state & use first found - if none add an extra record. That way you would avoid fragmentation. Not saying this is a good solution - just a way of avoiding fragmentation if you went down that route.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion PaulF, however I'd like to avoid having duplicate data if possible.

Comment: As I said - maybe not the best solution - but duplicate data can be avoided by clearing it in the record when flagging it as available for use. Norbert makes better points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query performance will be better in the long run:

What is happening with forever inserts:

> The table grows, indexes grow, index performance (lookup) is decreases with the size of the table, especially insert performance is hurt.

What is happening with delete:

> Table pages get fragmented, so the deleted space is not re-used 100% as expected, more near 50% in MySQL. So the table still grows to about twice the size you might expect for your amount of data. The index gets fragmented and becomes lob sided: It contains your new data but also the structure for your old data. It depends on the structure of your data on how bad this gets. This situation however stabilizes at a certain performance. This performance point has 2 benefits:
>
> 1) The table is more limited in size, so potential full table scans are faster
>
> 2) Your performance is predictable.
>
> Due to the fragmentation however this performance point is not equal to about twice your data amount, it tends to be a bit worse (benchmark it to see yourself). The benefit of the delete scenario is however since you have a smaller data set, that you might be able to rebuild your index once every reasonable period, thus improving your performance.

**Alternatives**

There are two alternatives you can look at to improve performance:

- Switch to MariaDB: This gains about 8% performance on large datasets (my observation, dataset just about 200GB compressed data)
- Look at partitioning: If you have a handy partitioning parameter, you can create a series of "small tables" for you and prevent logic for delete, rebuild and historic data management. This might give you the best performance profile.

Comment: I'm more worried about query performance than space. If space isn't an issue, would you say that option #2 is the better option then? If I'm reading correctly, the query performance hit isn't as bad with option 2.

Comment: I would use the constant delete, or partitioning. How is your data structured? Primary key etc (update your question with this and send a message, then I will take a look at that scenario).

Answer (score 1):

If most of the table is **flagged as deleted**, you will be stumbling over them as you look for the non-deleted records.  Adding `is_deleted` to many of the indexes is likely to help.

If you are **deleting records purely on age**, then `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))` is an excellent way to build the table.  The `DROP TABLE` is instantaneous and the `ALTER TABLE ... REORGANIZE ...` to create a new week (or month or ...) partition is also instantaneous.  See [*my blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) for details.

If you **"move" records** to another table, then the table will not shrink very fast due to fragmentation.  If you have enough disk space, this is not a bug deal.  If some queries need to see both current and archived records, use `UNION ALL`; it is pretty easy and efficient.